# unable to update live reload

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am running my hybrid app using

```
ionic serve
```

command, all works and app opens up in browser,
However whenever i change any of template in app/.. directory the changes gets reflected in www/build directory but ionic is unable to update live reload, it gives following error on console

```
ionic $ [10:37:06] Starting 'html'...
[10:37:06] Finished 'html' after 36 ms
HTML changed: D:\ge\Cordova_Poc\ionicv2-toturial\www\build\app.html
HTML changed: D:\ge\Cordova_Poc\ionicv2-toturial\www\build\pages\list\list.html
HTML changed: D:\ge\Cordova_Poc\ionicv2-toturial\www\build\pages\hello-ionic\hel
lo-ionic.html
HTML changed: D:\ge\Cordova_Poc\ionicv2-toturial\www\build\pages\item-details\it
em-details.html
Unable to update live reload: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.245.88.2:88
Unable to update live reload: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.245.88.2:88
Unable to update live reload: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.245.88.2:88
Unable to update live reload: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.245.88.2:88
```

I am not able to understand why ionic is trying to connect to 3.245.88.2 ?

Thanks.

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/unable-to-update-live-reload-error-connect-econnrefused/16923/14

Answer (score 0):

i have problem like that before, for me it was about the proxy, i have connected using proxy and i missed to set the default value of the proxy, so try to make look to your system proxy configuration and also your browser